# Do spider jockeys have unique drops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of a certian update, each mob has a unique 'special item' that it can drop upon death.

Spider-Jockeys are a unique mob, in that they are essentially a pair of mobs combined, with one riding atop the other.

Does this combined mob have a unique item drop?  Or does each individual 'part' of the mob have its own unique dropped items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spider jockeys behave in a similar way to a player riding a pig- they are two separate entities who take damage, die and drop loot individually.

Aside from how they spawn, the spider and skeleton are no different from any other. They will drop normal spider and skeleton loot.